# ASP.NET Core authorize-attribute not working with jwt

Tags: c#, jwt, http-status-code-401, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to implement JWT-based security in ASP.NET Core 3.1. My code is working when I use Visual Studio and run my api project from there. But when I am going to run the project from VS Code using dotnet cli `dotnet run`, then my login method works only and I am able to see the token in cookies but rest of my api like getting users gives unauthorised 401 to me.

**Links are as follows :**

- Visual Studio: https://localhost:44368/
- VS Code: https://localhost:5001/

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using DatingApp.API.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace DatingApp.API {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup (IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            //services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            //{
            //    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            //});
            services.AddSwaggerGen (c => {
                c.SwaggerDoc ("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
                    Title = "Dating App API",
                        Version = "v1"
                });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition ("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                        Name = "Authorization",
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement (new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[] { }
                    }
                });
            });
            services.AddMvc ().SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext> (x => x.UseSqlite (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddCors (options => {
                options.AddPolicy ("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin ()
                    .AllowAnyMethod ()
                    .AllowAnyHeader ());
            });
            services.Configure<CloudinarySettings> (Configuration.GetSection ("CloudinarySettings"));
            services.AddAutoMapper (typeof (DatingRepository).Assembly);
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository> ();
            services.AddScoped<IDatingRepository, DatingRepository> ();
            services.AddAuthentication (JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie (cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
                .AddJwtBearer (options => {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey (Encoding.ASCII
                    .GetBytes (Configuration.GetSection ("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment ()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler (builder => {
                    builder.Run (async context => {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature> ();
                        if (error != null) {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError (error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync (error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                // app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseSwagger ();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI (c => {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint ("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
            //  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting ();
            app.UseCors ("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication ();
            app.UseAuthorization ();
            app.UseEndpoints (endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllers ().RequireCors ("CorsPolicy");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

UserController.cs

[image]

Comment: clean your 'bin' and 'obj' and run again

Comment: @Mehrdad it's not working...